# SDAPS installation on XAMPP?

Tags: python, linux, installation, xampp, ocr

I need to install SDAPS, an Open Source OMR program, see here http://sdaps.org/SDAPS. It uses LaTeX and Python.
I have no idea if I can install it on XAMPP? Or do I need a Linux OS distribution? 
They write here: http://sdaps.org/Documentation/Dependencies about the Dependencies. How can I install those dependencies?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working on Debian Linux is as easy as `sudo apt-get install sdaps`. If you had read the [SDAPS download site](http://sdaps.org/Download) you would have known that:

> **Windows**
>
> There is no windows version for SDAPS. In theory it should be possible
> to get it running, but getting all the dependencies to work will be a
> big task.
>
> It is likely much simpler to install a GNU/Linux distribution on the
> computer or inside a virtual machine.

Comment: Thank you. Can I use this as a server version like on Apache? How to install on Xampp?

Comment: In [Dependencies](http://sdaps.org/Documentation/Dependencies) you mentioned, there is no word about any webserver. From what I see in [tutorial](http://sdaps.org/Documentation/Tutorial) it's just CLI program, so any further implementations can be possibly done within any server. I'm not familiar with SDAPS or any related solution, so I can't help with implementation.